# Apache Kafka Limitations

Tags: apache-kafka

I have worked on Apache Kafka programming and found the following overall limitations.

1. Issues with Message Tweaking
   As we know, the broker uses certain system calls to deliver messages to the consumer. However, Kafka’s performance reduces significantly if the message needs some tweaking. So, it can perform quite well if the message is unchanged because it uses the capabilities of the system.
2. Wildcard topic selection not supported
   There is an issue that Kafka only matches the exact topic name, that means it does not support wildcard topic selection. Because that makes it incapable of addressing certain use cases.
3. Reduces Performance
   In general, there are no issues with the individual message size. However, the brokers and consumers start compressing these messages as the size increases. Due to this, when decompressed, the node memory gets slowly used. Also, compress happens when the data flow in the pipeline. It affects throughput and also performance.
4. No Complete Set of Monitoring Tools
   It is seen that it lacks a full set of management and monitoring tools.
5. Lacks some Messaging Paradigms
   Some of the messaging paradigms are missing in Kafka like request/reply, point-to-point queues and so on.

I would like to know, are there any more overall limitations on using Apache Kafka?
Please share your experience, which will help everyone.

Comment: Not sure which other product you are comparing Kafka with, in high volume data platforms, I have found Kafka to be top-tier. #2 is available since 2016, #3 is observable only with low volume data, I do accept #5, but it's not the use case. Several other products don't have streaming capability and connectors with streaming frameworks. Everything has limitations, if use case is not for big data, Kafka possibly may not be suitable.

Comment: Ok thank you. Could you explain a bit more about " if use case is not for big data, Kafka possibly may not be suitable" ? Is this also a limitation?

Comment: I am probably comparing with Apache Beam. But, I have not tried any other effectively. Let me know if any other better comparative solutions.

Comment: You could compare it to Apache Pulsar.